# AS3 Facebook API: Access Token Error Message

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-opengraph, mobile-application, facebook-as3-api

I am working on an ActionScript Air Mobile project in FlashDevelop using the FacebookMobile API to get and sort users' friends lists. I'm currently using FacebookMobile.batchRequest() to get the information I want and it works fine.

Working code:

```
var installedBatch:Batch = new Batch();
installedBatch.add("me/friends?fields=installed,name", handleFriendsList);
FacebookMobile.batchRequest(installedBatch);
```

The resulting JSON object passed to handleFriendsList() contains a list of the user's friends. Each friend contains an id and a name field. Only friends who have the app installed contain the installed field which is set to "true". I would like to condense this down to one line using FacebookMobile.api(), but when I try I get and error.

Attempted code:

```
FacebookMobile.api("me/friends?fields=installed,name", handleFriendsList);
```

This should result in the same JSON object being passed to handleFriendsList(), but instead I get an error complaining that I don't have an active access token.

Error:

```
message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the 
current user."
```

The odd thing is that I only get this error with FacebookMobile.api() and it only happens when I ask for the installed and name fields. FacebookMobile.api() works just fine when I just ask for "me/friends" without specifying the installed and name fields.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Be aware while developing for facebook. They keep changing the Graph API frequently. Keep track of their developer page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try making the request using the `params` argument.

```
FacebookMobile.api("me/friends", handleFriendsList, {fields:"installed,name"});
```

Comment: That did the trick! I completely forgot to look at the params argument. Thanks for the help.